# What is the difference between fundamental vs. built-in types C++

Tags: c++, types

I'm reading my notes for my C++ class in my college. And it states that types can be classified into categories based on their relationship to the underlying hardware facilities:

- fundamental types - correspond directly to the hardware facilities
- built-in types - reflect the capabilities of the hardware facilities directly and efficiently

I understand that fundamental types are int, bool, char, double and so forth.
I always thought fundamental types are built-in types as they are built in within the C++ language. Or am I wrong? What is the difference between fundamental and built-in?

Comment: There is no such dichotomy in C++. Instead, there are [fundamental types and compound types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type).

Comment: You must have missed to note something along that lecture.

Comment: Or the notes are making something up.

Comment: Not as strong a source as the language reference, but note that the [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh279663.aspx#Anchor_2) explicitly treat them as synonyms

Comment: The standard has a section on fundamental types `[basic.fundamental]`, but as far as I know it doesn't refer to built-in types.

Comment: C++ officially does not make that differentiation, looks like some egghead made that up (which happens quite often)

Comment: @DYZ, why not post it as an answer?

Comment: @SergeyA Indeed.

Comment: The built-in types OP mentioned are probably referring to platform dependent types.

Answer (score 7):

There is no such dichotomy in C++. Instead, there are [fundamental types  and compound types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type). Fundamental types are also [informally known as built-in types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh279663.aspx#Anchor_2).

Comment: I don't know of any agreed upon definition for built-in types. I bet it could be argued that some compound types like pointers could be considered built-in, being that they are core language features and are close-to-hardware concepts.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, the standard makes it clear that pionters are compound types. https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic.types#basic.compound

Comment: @RSahu No doubt. My comment says "compound types like pointers" using pointers as an example of a compound type. My comment was meant to illustrate how not all reasonable definitions for built-in types make it synonymous with fundamental types.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, I see. fundamental types vs. built-in types.

Answer (score 0):

> built-in types - reflect the capabilities of the hardware facilities
>   directly and efficiently

The only reference I can find is at [senecac.on.ca Overview](https://scs.senecac.on.ca/~btp305/pages/content/scope.html) that is about *an object-oriented language*, not specifically C++.

C++, as others have pointed put, makes no difference for "fundamental types" and "built-in types", even "intrinsic types" or "primitive types", they all are synonyms.

Trying to figure out what the author of that sentence is trying to explain, I can think of the `size_t` type. It's not something that a CPU can use "as is". It's an **unsigned integer**, but *implementation-defined*. Once the implementation defines it, then it fits into that "built-in types" definition sentence.